# Fixing unexpected relationships shown on an Ancestry online tree?

Tags: ancestry.com

My direct paternal ancestors have been designated as indirect on Ancestry.com  (i.e. the relationship calculator shows 'grandfather of 2nd great aunt')

Can I correct this myself, or do I need to contact Ancestry and have them do it?

Comment: Welcome to Genealogy & Family History SE! Who do you have set as the HomePerson of this tree?

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  I edited your question to make it more clear what you were asking about. If I have changed the meaning, please use the edit link under your question to edit it.  I have removed your surname and location interests because they aren't relevant to the question. If you would like to post them for everyone to see, you can do so in your profile.

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand what idea you try to express. Is it correct to say that Ancestry states that you paternal ancestors are related to each other? Or does it show your direct ancestors as not direct? You may add the screenshot to your question explaining the situation.

Comment: To clarify: when you look at this ancestor's profile on Ancestry, he is described as "grandfather of 2nd great aunt" when he should be "4th great grandfather". Is that right? If so, check the path from him to you and see if there are any missing relationships that break the link from him to you. I haven't seen this, but I'd guess it could happen if a child isn't assigned to exactly the right pair of parents, for example, or if there are accidental duplicates in the tree.